# SQL Column result with comma and colon to PHP Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, explode

I have a sql query that, for each result returns a string like `1:One, 2:Two, 3:Three`.

Now I want to convert each one of these strings to a PHP array like this:

```
Array(
    1: One,
    2: Two,
    3: Three
)
```

I know that I could do that with one `explode` function inside another one but, isn't that too much overkill if I have 500+ results on the mysql query? Is there any better way to get something like that?

Here is a sample of the mysql code that creates something like the string result that I gave:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cast(concat(cast(number.id AS char),': ',number.name) AS char) order by number.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS all_active_numbers
```

**EDIT**

So here's an example of 2 possible returning rows from mysql:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   id    |              all_groups            |     groups_assigned    |
|   1     |   1:Team A, 2:Team B, 3:Team C     |        1:Team A        |
|   2     |   1:Team A, 2:Team B, 3:Team C     |   2:Team B, 3:Team C   |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I want to know is the best way to transform the strings of `all_groups` and `groups_assigned` of each row, into a PHP array. As I said, I know I could do it using 2 `explode` function (one inside another using foreach loops) but what if my query returns 500+ results? This seems like a big overkill for the server to compute `explode's` for each one of the 500+ rows.

Just to clarify, `all_groups` is something like the groups that are available for a person and `groups_assigned` is the groups where the person is registered from the available `all_groups`.

Another possibility is maybe divide this into 3 different queries?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: show the result how is? row1|1|One row2|2|Two????

Comment: i would do it with explode. Maybe you can concat it to json array and do json_decode but i dont know if its faster

Comment: if you're just going to split up the data in the client, then don't smoosh the data together in mysql in the first place...

Comment: I updated the info of my question with a more detailed example.

Comment: @MarcB The real query is much more complicated with something like 6 joins and one other `GROUP_CONCAT`. In other words, it's too hard to explain here and so, I tried to simplify the question. Please see my new edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `explode` based off of your colon, otherwise, form your query to provide the KEY and VALUE's separately.

PHP example (untested, example only):

```
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$myArray = array();
while($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $myGroup = explode(": ", $row['all_active_numbers']);
  $myArray[][$myGroup[0]] = $myGroup[1];
}
var_dump($myArray);
```

Comment: i think his string looks like this "1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three" for one row

Comment: I had thought this; there will need to be some sort of "per row" delimiter.. maybe he can figure that out himself with the provided example to get him pointed in the right direction!

Comment: @RobW I updated the info of my question with a more detailed example. Please, see my Edit =).

Comment: @CristianoSantos - Even with a million rows of data, it won't really strain PHP/the web server. Your database query should just query the data, and your script should transform/handle the data. Hope this helps!

Comment: @RobW So the transformation of the string in array in each one of the rows doesn't slow down the Server significantly? Even with a `foreach` inside another one using 2 `explode` functions?

Comment: Doubtful / unnoticeable to humans. You could do some `microtime()` testing to see if you're able to do both methods.